# Customizing Rally TaskBoard app with Settings

Tags: rally

I'm customizing TaskBoard app (https://github.com/RallyApps/TaskBoard) for the company needs and would like to add Settings menu item.
Does anyone know how to do this for this old-style app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reached the Rally support team and their response was the following:

> Thanks for reaching out to Rally Support regarding custom app coding
>   for the TaskBoard app. Unfortunately, there is not a good example of
>   how to do this, however, ow that the latest AppSDK candidate has fixed
>   settings panel problems, you're best off with the example in the docs
>   at:
>
> https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc3/doc/#!/guide/settings

So, I think it's not really possible to do this.